# Why $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$ for $x,y\in D[0,1]$ equipped with skorohod distance?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$D=D[0,1]$ is the space of real functions on $[0,1]$ that are right-continuous and have left-hand limits:
(i) For $0\leq t <1,\ x(t^+)=\lim_{s\downarrow t}x(s)$ exits and $x(t^+)=x(t)$;
(ii) For $0<t\leq 1,\ x(t^-)=\lim_{s\uparrow t}x(s)$ exits.

Define the skorohod distance function on D as $d(x,y)=\inf_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\{ \Vert \lambda-I\Vert\vee\Vert x-y\lambda\Vert\}$, where $\Lambda$ denote the class of strictly increasing continous function of $[0,1]$ onto itself, $I$ denotes the identity function on $[0,1]$, $\Vert.\Vert$ is $\Vert x\Vert=\sup_t |x(t)|$, and $x,y\in D$.

In page 124 of Convergence of Probability Measure, Prof. Billingsley says that **"$d(x,y)=0$ implies that for each $t$ either $x(t)=y(t)$ or $x(t)=y(t^-)$, which in turn implies $x=y$."**

I am very puzzled with the bolded sentence, and don't know how exactly Prof. Billingsley proved the implications. The following is my thought. Can you provide any help for proving $d(x,y)$ implies $x=y$?

---

$d(x,y)=0$ implies $\forall\epsilon,\exists\lambda\ s.t\ \Vert\lambda t-t\Vert<\epsilon \ and \ \Vert x-y\lambda\Vert<\epsilon$. Then for each t, we can get $|\lambda t-t|<\epsilon \ and \ |x(t)-y(\lambda t)|<\epsilon$. If $y$ is continuous at point $t$, then by letting $\epsilon$ go to 0 we can get $x(t)=y(t)$.

---

But how about $y$ is not continuous at point $t$? and what is the rest of the proof? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\in D$, let $K_y$ denote the set of points of continuity of $y$. Note that the complement of $K_y$ is countable.
If $t\notin K_y$, there is a sequence $\{s_n\} \subset K_y$ such that $s_n \downarrow t.$ Then for $x \in D$, the equalities $x(s_n)=y(s_n)$ imply that $x(t)=y(t)$.